# Restrict php script to only one computer without login

Tags: php, security, authentication

I want to make a php webpage accessible from only one computer.

IP checking isn't suitable for that (Dynamic IP).

I could set a cookie (with no expiration date) with a token. Then I could check if the cookie has the correct token and display the page, else I could die(). I think that this isn't a secure solution, because a cookie can be stolen, can't it?

So, what to do?

P.S. Obviously I can't login every time.

Comment: Check out this: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Comment: [PHP Authentication](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php)

Comment: @Sergey thanks, but I don't want to login every time!

Comment: [SSL client certificates](https://www.google.com/search?q=ssl+client+certificates+howto) might do the job.

Comment: @RenePot Simply I can't, sorry.

Comment: SSL client certs would absolutely be my answer too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here are a couple of options:

#### Client side certificates

[Create a client side certificate](http://www.garex.net/apache/) and configure your webserver to authenticate using client certificates. **Problem solved.** In future, if you need to have more computers connect to the server, give them client certificates as well.

#### IP based : using Dynamic DNS

Give your computer a dynamic-dns name (myclient.dyndns.com) and install a dyndns client on your computer. The dyndns client keeps checking its own IP and updates the nameserver entry whenever your computer's IP changes. On server side all you need to check is if the IP that the requester presents is same as *myclient.dyndns.com* and allow access if it is. 
A slight gotcha in this one is that there is a small (configurable) window of time between when IP changes and the dyndns client pupulates it to the nameserver. So, whenever your IP changes, until the dyndns client on your computer detects it and updates the nameserver, your server will not allow any requests from your computer in that time window. Thats because your computer will present the new IP and myclient.dyndns.com will resolve to your old UP. This time window can be made as small as you want (even 1 second). The other small gotcha is that in this n second window, any random computer that gets your old IP assigned by the ISP can access your server. The probablity of this is very small but just mentioning as a possibility.

There are many free dynamic dns services out there. You can google them.

#### Cookie Based

You could use cookies. However as you correctly identified, cookies can be stolen. Now, there are two ways they can be stolen:

- **Copying the cookie off the computer:** Someone who has access to the computer can copy that specific cookie and impersonate as your computer to your webserver. If this is possible (if potential malicious users can remote desktop or physically access your computer), then cookie based solution is not for you.
- **Sniffing over the network:** Cookies can be easily sniffed over the network. A easy way to prevent sniffing is enabling SSL. Given that you are confident that cookies cannot be stolen off the computer by copying it over, cookie+SSL option works in your case. In this case its just like a shared secret key. You do it via cookie or querystring, it doesn't matter. Cookie obviously are preferred over querystring because cookies aren't normally logged in browser history or webserver logs.

Also just a thought: For all the computers that aren't authenticated, send a standard 404 response rather than some custom "Access denied" page. This way anyone who is running a crawler/bot/scanner on your site will not be intrigued by this custom response and will not attempt to circumvent your security controls.

Comment: Very comprehensive answer. What if I change the httpd conf to request certs, pass certificate's parameter as Env Var to PHP and then do the authentication check directly in PHP?

Comment: Another question: your link about ssl client certificates talks about an authentication scheme based only on Organization and Dept parameters. What will happen if a bad guy creates a new CA, creates new certificate with same parameters and uses it to login?

Thank you very much for your effort!

Comment: @Surferonthefall So there is a trust angle in this certificate business. So for example, when gmail.com presents you a ssl certificate, your browser knows to trust it because it trusts the CA (which is added in the trusted CA list in your browser/OS settings).
Similarly when you use client certificate, you'll add the CA of that client cert to your trusted cert folder in your webserver. A bad guy can create CA and certs but the public/private keys of that cert will be different and your webserver identifies certs based on keys (fingerprint) and not on the parameters you use to create a cert.

Comment: Thanks, but your link talks about dept and organisation, he further do the login with username/password (authbasic). If I don't want the authbasic, how can I allow login checking only the cert data? Choosing a long random string as department could be a pseudo-password scheme. What do you think about it? Thanks again

Comment: @Surferonthefall You can skip those sections in that article. Creating a simple client certificate (plus CA) and requiring apache to expect client certificate (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_howto.html#allclients) should suffice.

Comment: @Shivam, how can dynamic DNS possibly work? Apache is going to perform a reverse DNS lookup from your IP, and that's NOT going to get myclient.dyndyns.com instead it will get whatever your ISP says it is, such as c-99-99-99-99.hsd1.co.comcast.net.  If you hardcode the IP address in httpd.conf, you have essentially defeated the purpose of dynamic dns.

Comment: The idea is that whenever any person requests apache for a page, apache asks John the name of the person he is supposed to give data to. Suppose John says "Give data only to bob", then apache verifies that the person asking for data is indeed bob. If its not, apache denies giving the page. Any time bob changes his name (lets say he is Tom now), he just rings John to tell that he goes by the name of Tom now. John will now start saying "Give data only to Tom" to whosoever asks him the question "Whom should I give data to?"
In my example, client.dyndns.com is John. Authorized IP is Bob (or Tom)

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just use a unique passphrase as a parameter in the uri?
e.g. http://www.example.com/index.php?passphrase=sfauh452h8243nf2489ht8924t48nf3984

and check to see if it matches the one stored in the server?

Well I get if you are not the user it is someone else... then you need only that specific client (computer) to be able to access the page

Either way the first time there must be some sort of registration. Maybe the example uri above works like this:
you request: http://www.example.com/index.php?passphrase=sfauh452h8243nf2489ht8924t48nf3984
the passphrase is checked of being correct and a boolean value is stored in the server as to never be able to "register" again.
If it is correct, a cookie is being generated with a unique key.
This same key is also stored in the server (file, database or something)

Therefore on subsequent requests when you just compare the key stored in the server and the key in the cookie you know who is the client

Comment: In fact, that is the auth scheme currently used. I have suddenly realized that it is relatively easily to sniff (getting referrer trough an image hot-linked, scraping web history, log viewing and so on). I'm going to switch to ssl client. Thanks anyway!